# Compiler finds nil while trying to remove all snapshotListeners

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have a logout function in my app where I want to remove all the listeners being used in the app. To do this, I use an Observable Object class that manages my listeners.

```
class ListenersManager: ObservableObject{

@Published var listeners: [ListenerRegistration?] = []


func removeAllListeners(){
    
    for i in listeners{
       
        if i == nil{}
        
        else{
        i!.remove()
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then I inject it into the app as an environmentObject

This is how I initialize the listeners and add them to my listenersManager

```
    @EnvironmentObject var listenersManager: ListenersManager
    @State var driversCollListener: ListenerRegistration?

    .onAppear(perform: {

        listenersManager.listeners.append(driversCollListener)

     driversCollListener = db.collection("adminData").document(email).collection("drivers").whereField("cv", isEqualTo: 1).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, err) in
        if err != nil{fatalError("Could not extract admin's drivers data")}

            if driversCollListener != nil{
        
        for driver in snapshot!.documents{
            
            if myDrivers.contains("\(driver.documentID)"){
                
            }else{
            myDrivers.append(driver.documentID)
                print(myDrivers)
           
            }
        }
                
            }
            else{}
    
    
    }
   }
```

And this is where I call to remove all the listeners

```
                Button(action: {
                
                listenersManager.removeAllListeners()
                
                try? auth.signOut()
                navStack.pop(to: .root)
                
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign Out")
                    .font(Font.custom("Roboto-Light", size: 14))
                
            })
```

However this is the error that appears when I click the Sign out button

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: Don't use `!` It will crash if the variable is `nil`.- You can simply say `i?.remove()`.  Similarly, say `for driver in snapshot?.documents ?? []`

Comment: Also, an array of optionals doesn't make much sense.  You should declare `@Published var listeners: [ListenerRegistration] = []` and simply not store the listener if it is nil

Comment: dont know why stackoverflow doesn't reccommend thanking people. Thank you! You're a life saver @Paulw11

Comment: It is perfectly ok to thank someone in a comment - you’re welcome by the way. It is advised not to include “thank you” in your question itself as it is just extra words.

Comment: @Paulw11 That's a great observation and a proper coding solution. Can you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always try to eliminate forced operations (unwrap, downcast and try) in Swift; Every time you use ! to force something you risk a crash.  I am not saying you should never use these operations, but don't simply add a ! to satisfy the compiler.  Think about how you can complete the operation safely.

In your code you can easily eliminate the forced unwraps:

```
func removeAllListeners(){
    
    for i in listeners{
       i?.remove()
    }
}
```

```
 if driversCollListener != nil{
        
    for driver in snapshot?.documents ?? []{
            
    if !myDrivers.contains("\(driver.documentID)"){
        myDrivers.append(driver.documentID)
        print(myDrivers)    
    }
}
```

An array with an optional element type also doesn't make much sense; If the element is `nil`, don't add it to the array in the first place, so use

```
@Published var listeners: [ListenerRegistration] = []

func removeAllListeners(){
    
    for listener in listeners{
       listener.remove()
    }
}
```